# docker-compose.yml nginx with php link

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I tried this in the `docker-compose.yml` file but can't get php working in the nginx server. What I try to do is simply have nginx with php working

```
  web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./docker-nginx-php/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  links:
    - php
php:
  image: php:7-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./docker-nginx-php/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Hope someone knows how to get it working!

I have on my host system `apache2 installed` which serves some of my apps but I want to have `nginx with php` server another domain so port 80 is currently in use by `apache2` listener that's why I use port `8080:80` instead in this example above

Comment: Is this your whole config file? if not, can you also share the rest of it? And can you also check the logs of your php container in order to verify that this one starts correctly? As well as checking your nginx container for any errors

Comment: This is the whole `config file` I just need it to run `nginx` with `php` I don't know where to find the `logs` in this configuration. I'm new to `Docker containers`.

Comment: You can easily do this by installing portainer, which allows you to inspect the logs: https://www.portainer.io/

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the environment variable `VIRTUAL_HOST` on the php container as well as opening the port within docker for connection with other containers, like:

```
php:
  image: php:7-fpm
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.example.com
  ports:
    - 80
  volumes:
    - ./docker-nginx-php/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: still same error here: http://prntscr.com/lweegt even after adding this

Comment: Added another suggestion

Comment: btw I edited my question because it might be because I use `apache2` on my host and want `nginx docker with php` to host another site that's why `port 80` is in use by `apache2 listener` and I have the containers run on `port 8080:80` but can't find a solution to get it working with `php`